# Cannot set property 'value' of null for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to set a value to an input text field but I get the error `Cannot set property 'value' of null`

I have set the name and ID to `hdnContactID`:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" name="hdnContactID" id="hdnContactID" style="display:none"/>
```

But then in the javascript code when I try to set a value to `hdnContactID` I get the error:

```
document.getElementById('hdnContactID').value = result.ID;
```

result.ID is returning a number but how is it not finding `hdnContactID`?

Comment: Are you calling the javascript before the page is loaded?

Comment: Mhm... Maybe because there is no item with the ID `hdnContactID` :3

Comment: @TCHdvlp  id="hdnContactID"  is present , but looks like James nailed it

Answer (score 6):

This input is marked with `runat="server"`, so is an asp.net controlled input.  It will have an autogenerated ID on the client side, but you can get hold of it still using the [`ClientID` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
document.getElementById('<%=hdnContactID.ClientID%>').value = result.ID;
```

This of course requires that your JavaScript code is also contained within the aspx, otherwise you'll need to create a variable to hold this ID which you set within the aspx, and access wherever your JavaScript actually is.